# Android Uri building ignore parameters except if at least one parameter is present

Tags: android, pdf, webview, uri

I have a strange behaviour when I click on a link in a webview that is a PDF file link.
For example: https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf

So I have made some research and this link will start a dowload in my webview.
I have a DownloadListener and a onDownloadStart method.
In it I send the URL to Android so that PDF apps on phone can open it.

My strange behaviour is here. If the link in the webview does not have parameters I am not able to add parameters in the URL **but** if the URL have one parameter -> my parameters are added.

Example will be more meaningful.

Here `url` in link is "https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf"

```
val uriTest = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("key1", val1)
    .appendQueryParameter("key2", val2)
    .build()
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriTest) 
startActivity(intent)
```

So when the PDF app called by `startActivity(intent)` call the URL on my server I have no parameters in URL and on my server I see a call to "https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf" **not to** "https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf?key1=val1&key2=val2".

BUT

If the `url` in link is "https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf?t=t" when my Android code is executed on my server side I can see a call to ""https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf?t=t&key1=val1&key2=val2". My parameters are added in this case.

Is it normal? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

---EDIT---
I also tried to add my parameters in the string directly and it is the same -> my parameters are ignored until the URL I get has one parameter.
Example: I get "https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf" and I do:

```
val url1 = url + "?key1=" + val1
or
val url1 = "$url?key1=$val1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    val yourUrl = StringBuilder("https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf")
    val parameters = hashMapOf<String, String>()
    parameters["key1"] = "val1"
    parameters["key2"] = "val2"

    var count = 0
    for (i in parameters.entries) {
        if (count == 0)
            yourUrl.append("?${i.key}=${i.value}&")
        else
            yourUrl.append("${i.key}=${i.value}&")
        count++
    }

    val yourNewUrl = yourUrl.substring(0, yourUrl.length - 1)
    Timber.e("URL: $yourNewUrl")

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(yourNewUrl))
    startActivity(intent)
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) But I tried to add my parameters directly in the url as a string (like you do here) and nothing work... Only if the URL I get has already one parameter... (I will add this information in my question)

Comment: I'm just edited answer. If it's not what you want then just show me the final link which you want to get after adding parameters.

Comment: yes this is not working nether... I mean I can add parameters on Android side but on server side parameters are not sent if the url has not one parameter when I get it. The URL I want is simple https://my.server.com/foobar.pdf?key1=val1&key2=val2. Of course your code works just like add them directly in the string but on server side I do not get parameters